# How to differentiate IPN and PDT request/response

Tags: php, paypal

I am not a php expert nor a web developer, but I've developed my own shopping cart in php and am hoping to intergrate PayPal. I've done a lot of readings and used some sample code with not much luck (half working). I am still hoping to be able to implement it, my questions are:

1. How do you differentiate if a request/response is IPN or PDT?
2. On a topic regarding IPN vs PDT, an answer said:

   With PDT you get the notification instantly and can do any additional processing required and show the user a confirmation page.

   With IPN you are guaranteed to be notified that the payment was received even if the user's computer explodes before it can send you the PDT.
3. Why can't IPN be used to display a confirmation page? I understand that IPN can also be triggered by PayPal or user, for example, a buyer initiates a dispute, and the listener handles the notification, hence under this situation, it can't be used to display confirmation page. But since you also specified a return URL with IPN, , then why can't this return URL be a page that displays a confirmation message or a thank you message? Provided that the trigger was a new payment was made/completed, etc. Or is there no way to tell who initiates a request/response?
4. Since IPN and PDT are so similar (in fact, I don't know how to differentiate them), the information passing back and forth is the same, why can't I use IPN's return URL to display messages such as thank you for your purchase?
5. Also, with question 2, point (b), won't u still get the PDT message even if the user's computer explodes as long as the transaction completed prior? :)

I am a bit lost, please help me with answers rather than asking me "why do you want to do that?", because if I know, I won't be here seeking help. If you think I am totally missing the point, explain it to me and help me.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_OrderManagement_IntegrationGuide/intro.html

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll have a read (have two young children), hope u don't mind if I come back to ask you more questions :)

Comment: @Matt thanks for the link, it says ssl is not required for IPN, does it mean ssl is required for PDT? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since I found it, someone else might.
Most of your questions are answered [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/).

As you can see, Paypal recommends implementing **both** IPN and PDT if you want to display a confirmation page immediately.

Now to answer your questions:

1) You can differentiate between IPN and PDT easily:

- first of all, they need to be activate by you manually, so you can't have one "by accident". You, or whoever owns the Paypal account you are going to use, needs to enable PDT in `Paypal/Profile/My Selling Tools/Website Preferences/Website Payment Preferences/PDT - Payment Data Transfer`. In order to use PDT, Auto Return will also have to be setup (although you can override Auto Return on a per-transaction basis).
- IPN will send the data using HTTP POST, PDT will send data appended to your Return URL as HTTP GET data. Again, huge difference.
- you need to instruct Paypal that you want you use IPN and let them know the `notify_url` parameter, which will be your listener (handler) script on your server, so again, you cannot get an IPN without you specifically asking for it.

2) That is correct, IPN will make sure you get the notification even if the user's computer explodes after paying, before sending the PDT.

- PDT is only sent once, IF the user makes it back to your site, as it will be appended to the Return URL you gave Paypal (see above). If the user unplugs its computer after paying, but before being redirected to your site (or the computer explodes...) you will never get the PDT data in the HTTP GET! Of course, your server might also explode, and again you never get the PDT data, but with IPN, if you recover your server in a few days, you will still get the notification.
- in contrast, IPN is sent multiple times, until you confirm to Paypal you got it. So Paypal will HTTP POST the IPN data to your server, to the listener script, until you tell him "ok, i got it".
- IPN might take some time, while PDT is instant, but unreliable, that is why Paypal recommends you implement both (see the link above).

3) Because it is not instant... although the name would imply that. It might take longer than the time needed for the user to be redirected to your site. To quote from the link at the start of my answer: "*With IPN, however, there is a material lag between the time a customer completes payment and the time your site receives notification of this event.*"

4) See above the differences, they are not that similar. The data carried back and forth is not the same, IPN carries more data than PDT. Also, PDT cannot be used for recurring events, like subscriptions. IPN is the only choice. Again, see the link at the top for

5) I think I already answered that, but in short, no, you won't get the PDT data if the user's computer or your server explodes before they get a chance to return to your site.

Hope that helps.